# How to create a non-TH package from code generated using Template Haskell?

Tags: haskell, tuples, template-haskell

I'm making a small package that defines wrappers for tuples and adds instances form them, like

```
newtype Tuple2 a = Tuple2 { untuple2 :: (a, a) }
  deriving (...)

tuple2 :: a -> a -> Tuple2 a
tuple2 = ...

instance Traversable Tuple2 where ...
instance Foldable Tuple2 where ...
instance Functor Tuple2 where ...
instance Applicative Tuple2 where ...
```

This repeats from 2 to [15](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2978389/1333025), so it looks like a job for Template Haskell.

The generated code is always Haskell 98 compatible, so I'd like the final result to be a Haskell 98 compatible package too. **Is it possible to generate a piece of code using Template Haskell and make a package from it that doesn't use TH itself?** (I'd prefer an automated way, if possible.)

Answer (score 4):

There are tools for it:

- [EvilSplicer](http://source.git-annex.branchable.com/?p=source.git;a=blob;f=Build/EvilSplicer.hs;h=e07034c5b05f47c316a1e68e6a85d54335c8e253;hb=aaa841e60a55524c3efb5e9783b8e6074d2413cc) (removed from sources [on 13 Oct 2018](http://source.git-annex.branchable.com/?p=source.git;a=commitdiff;h=38d691a10febf9590dd3639defa0e4f38ec3648c)), written by [Joey Hess](http://joeyh.name/blog/entry/Template_Haskell_on_impossible_architectures/) before he discovered
- [zeroth](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zeroth), which does not seem to be in active development any more.

Disclaimer: I have not tried any of these myself.

Comment: I tried zeroth, but it doesn't compile. I'll try to contact the original author.

Answer (score 2):

It's always possible to just write a Haskell program that outputs Haskell source code as an ordinary text file. You can then compile that like any other file.

What this doesn't give you, of course:

- Syntax checking. (I.e., the code you generate might contain syntax errors.)
- The ability to inspect hand-written code already compiled.
- The ability to use other GHC features like type inference.

Comment: A long time before TH and syb, I wrote so many program writing programs that I wrote a program writing program writing program. It read source code from a .rtf file and put the code at each different level based on the colour of the text! I'm not sure if I ever ported it from Gofer to Haskell, but it was fun anyway.

Comment: That is an option, yes, but my question asked specifically for a TH solution.